# Expandable Grid with jQuery (Demo attached)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, accordion, expandable

I am trying to rebuild a similar function like this, scroll to **our family**

**http://www.ludlowventures.com/**

But without success :-( can anybody help? A example with Bootstrap in JS Fiddle or similar woud be perfect! I have tried a lot but nothing to show cause all was not working as expected!

Cheers[image: Demo Image]

Comment: Have you an example of what you tried already?

Comment: Isn't that just a basic grid with lazy loading?

Comment: No sorry, all example were stupid and I think the wrong beginning!! NO lazy load required, it's more a **Accordion** but not in default Layout, and Content to expand is not inside the Item!!